# Javascript validation check box issue with Joomla v3.3

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, javascript, validations

I tried to implement a check box to go to the products pages of this joomla v3:
http://www.nordicpharma.com/es/nuestros-productos.html

Two methods was used without success !

http://jsfiddle.net/moja/es9oar4y/

jsfiddle.net/moja/mb8u4u99/

Libraries used to try it:
jQuery library ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js
ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.migrate/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

Do you know in which direction I have to search for ?

Comment: I'm a little confused here. The validation seems to be working. If I click submit **without** checking the checkbox then an alert message appears, else it redirects be to a page displaying some results. Are you expecting something different? If so then please explain in more detail

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Joomla v3.3 includes jQuery v1.11.1. You should not replace it with a previous version. It can cause general problems.

Secondly, the Javascript validation routine is not included in the page.

About the second validation, Joomla does not implement jQuery with the $ sign, you have to call it with jQuery, for example: jQuery('#checky').